# AudioManager Sound Effects Only Working on Some Devices

Tags: android, audio, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a soft keyboard in android that extends `InputMethodService`. Users of the keyboard can enable or disable sound effects while they are typing. I am using the Android `AudioManager` class

When the service is initialized, I check to see if the preference is set to play sound effects. In here I obtain a reference to an `AudioManager` object, and after some fiddling call `loadSoundEffects()`.

In my subclass's implementation of `onKey(int, int[])` I call this method if the preference is set to play sound effects.

```
private void playSoundEffect(int keyCode) {
    int sound = AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD;
    if (keyCode == 32)
        sound = AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR;
    else if (keyCode == MyKeyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE)
        sound = AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE;
    else if (keyCode == MyKeyboard.KEYCODE_DONE || keyCode == 10)
        sound = AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN;
    Log.i("Lex", "sound=" + sound);
    mAudioManager.playSoundEffect(sound);
}
```

I've tested this code on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (on API 21) and on two models of Alcatel Ideal phones (running API 21 and 24). The sound effects only play on the Samsung phone.

After doing some research it seems that the sound effects simply aren't included on the Alcatel devices.

**Is there a way to check to see if the sound effects exist programmatically?** If I am using `AuidoManager` correctly and the sound effects aren't present **I'd like to check for their existence, and if they do *not* exist disable the option for the user to turn on sound effects at all.**